# Film where the black psychic is tricked into drinking Long Island Iced Teas, causing him to miss the monster

Tags: story-identification, movie

This came upon me when I was at Applebee's tonight with my wife, and the topic came up of when the chain was offering $1 Long Island Iced Teas. I suddenly remembered a scene from a film I saw part of in high school (1995-1998). It was set in modern times, with this team hunting a monster. One of the members of the team was a black psychic. The team's at a bar and it turns out he doesn't drink, so the group suggests a "non-alcoholic" [Long Island Iced Tea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_Island_Iced_Tea) (for those not in on the joke, Long Island Iced Tea is a mix of various alcohols, and a bit of cola, with no tea in the mix. It's generally very potent stuff). Cue a scene where he stumbles out in the alleyway, and blearily regards the monster, before he walks away, unharmed, only to realize upon sobering up that he encountered the creature.

I honestly don't remember what happened in the rest of the film, but that scene stuck with me, and it seems a distinctive enough one to be searchable.

Comment: This should not be tagged as a duplicate. The questions are not at all even close to the same. Just because the answers are duplicates it doesn't mean the questions are duplicates. Searching for terms in this question won't turn up the other one so there would be no way to know it was a duplicate.

Comment: It's policy for [Story-identification].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surprisingly (perhaps) this is the 1995 big-budget science fiction thriller *[Species](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114508/)*.  The African-American character is Dan Smithson, an "empath" played by the wonderful Forest Whitaker.

[The scene in question](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=species) occurs a little over an hour into the movie, when most of the characters, including the titular monster, are at a bar.

> **Smithson:**  What do you call this?
>   **Arden:**  It's called a Long Island Ice Tea.
>   **Smithson:**  It's got tea in it?
>   **Arden:**  Nope.
>
> [interlude during with the alien talks with Marg Helgenberger's character in the ladies' room]
>
> **Lennox:**  One Long Island Ice Tea.
>   **Smithson:**  I like these cups of tea.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species_(film)):

> During the SETI program, Earth's scientists send out transmissions (shown to be the Arecibo message) with information about Earth and its inhabitants, DNA structure, etc., in hopes of finding life beyond Earth. They then receive transmissions from an alien source on how to create endless fuel effortlessly. Therefore, the scientists assume that this is a friendly alien species. From a second alien transmission, the scientists receive information about an alien DNA along with instructions on how to splice it with human DNA. A government team led by Xavier Fitch (Ben Kingsley) goes forward with the genetic experiment attempting to induce a female, under the (later proved to be mistaken) assumption that a female would have "more docile and controllable" traits. One of the hundred experimental ova produces a girl named Sil, who looks like a normal human but develops into a 12-year-old in 3 months.
>
> Sil's violent outbursts during sleep make the scientists consider her a threat. They try to kill her using cyanide gas but she breaks out of her containment cell and escapes. The government assembles a team composed of anthropologist Dr. Stephen Arden (Alfred Molina), molecular biologist Dr. Laura Baker (Marg Helgenberger), "empath" Dan Smithson (Forest Whitaker) and mercenary Preston "Press" Lennox (Michael Madsen) to track and destroy Sil. Sil matures rapidly into an adult (Natasha Henstridge) in her early twenties and makes her way to Los Angeles. Her body strength, regenerative ability and intelligence make tracking her extremely difficult. The scientists fear she may mate with human males and produce offspring that could eliminate the human race. Sil is intent on producing offspring as soon as possible, and kills several people to prevent them from notifying the authorities or simply to use their clothing.
>
> Sil first tries to mate with a man she meets at a nightclub (Anthony Guidera), but after sensing that he is diabetic, she rejects him. Unsatisfied, he tries to rape her, prompting her to kill him by puncturing his skull with her tongue. She then tries to mate with John Carey (Whip Hubley), a man she meets after a car accident. They swim in Carey's pool where Sil forces him to open his swimming trunks in order to mate, but he refuses. This act is interrupted by Preston and Laura. She kills Carey, morphing into her alien form, a bipedal mutant with tentacles on her shoulders and back, and flees naked into a forest without being seen by the team. She pretends to be a rape victim to kidnap a woman (Marliese K. Schneider) in order to assume her identity. Sitting in the car near Carey's home, she reads Fitch's lips, as she had done earlier, **learning of their plan to stake out the nightclub for her return. There, she is seen by Dan, prompting a car chase.** She fakes her death by crashing the car, which she has previously filled with gasoline containers, into a high-voltage transformer, using the kidnapped woman as a stand-in for her own body.
>
> After cutting and dyeing her hair, Sil takes an attraction to Preston, having dreamt of him the previous night. After the team celebrates their apparent victory, she stalks them in their hotel, and they do not recognize her. Arden, who is upset at being single, walks into his room to find Sil waiting there. She has intercourse with Arden, which results in her instantly getting impregnated by him, then kills him when he realizes who she is. Dan senses that Sil is in the hotel and he alerts Preston, Laura, and the rest of the team. She morphs again, escapes and they follow her into the sewers where Fitch is subsequently killed. Sil gives birth and Dan finds her offspring in a cavern behind the sewers. The child attacks him and he incinerates it, also killing Sil. The trio leaves the area. The last scene shows a rat chewing on one of Sil's severed tentacles; it starts to mutate into a vicious beast and attacks another rat.

Comment: That would fit the timeframe and the details. Thank you. That one was bugging me.

Answer (score 2):

Species 1995. Is around one hour and 16 minutes.